Create movable object and shapes in Flutter
Good evening everyone,
I'm relatively new to Flutter and currently working on a shape maker app. The user can create several points, which are automatically connected with straight lines, and then these points can be moved, which is displayed on the screen:


The best I could come up with was to use Draggable and track its status - this question and the discussions in it helped me a lot. But I don’t quite understand how to expand this concept to a large number of points and the logic of their relative position (separation of internal points from external ones, closing the contour of a figure, etc.).
I also checked the similar question, but in remained unanswered.
I suspect there must be some better solution, but I haven't been able to find it yet. I would be very grateful if you could describe some general concept of what such a solution could look like. If a similar question has already been asked, I apologize in advance and would be grateful for a link or source. Thanks!
